# How do I contribute to CircuiTikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, contribute

## Update (29 Dec 2012)

The author has already update CircuiTikZ (Thank you, Massimo!). It should be integrated into the CTAN official repositories in a few days. The package is now hosted in Github for easier collaboration at https://github.com/mredaelli/circuitikz

---

I'm having difficulty contacting the author of `circuitikz`. The email address listed in the README no longer exists; delivery fails permanently.

I needed a fully differential operational amplifier `fd op amp`, so I created a shape for it.

Kindly have a look at my code at https://github.com/kitmonisit/circuitikz

Some caveats:

1. Basically I added it to `pgfcirctripoles.sty`. It's supposed to be a quadpole, but I could not figure out how to add it to `pgfcircquadpoles.sty` and simply changing the declaration line to `\pgfdeclarequadpole`
2. I may not have followed the convention in specifying the coordinates to enable dynamic scaling. I'll just call out the following new parts so you can check them easily: new anchors `out-`, `out+`, and the new output terminals which have been commented with `% Positive output terminal` and `% Negative output terminal`

I'm hoping that this new shape will be integrated into the next official version of CircuiTikZ.

### Example usage

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}

\usepackage[siunitx]{circuitikz}

\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/height/.initial=.4854}
\ctikzset{bipoles/capacitor/width/.initial=.1}

\begin{document}%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw
  (0,0) node[fd op amp] (opamp) {} node[left] {\(A\)}
  % Input
  (opamp.-) node[circ] {} to[C, l_=\(C_s\)] ++(-1.5,0) node[ocirc] {} node[left] {\(v_i^-\)}
  (opamp.+) node[circ] {} to[C, l=\(C_s\)] ++(-1.5,0) node[ocirc] {} node[left] {\(v_i^+\)}
  % Feedback
  (opamp.-) -- ++(0,1)  to[C, l=\(C_f\)] ++(2,0) -| (opamp.out+) {}
  (opamp.+) -- ++(0,-1) to[C, l_=\(C_f\)] ++(2,0) -| (opamp.out-) {}
  % Output
  (opamp.out +) node[circ] {} -- ++(1,0) node[ocirc] {} node[right] {\(v_o^+\)}
  (opamp.out -) node[circ] {} -- ++(1,0) node[ocirc] {} node[right] {\(v_o^-\)}
  ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Fully differential operational amplifier]

Comment: To get the new email address, follow the instructions in the footnote on page 2 of the manual (ver. Sept. 2011). I wrote him more than a month ago too, but he didn't reply at all. I suspect the development is quiescent.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I'm a circuitikz addict and I was happy to find a fully diff opamp already made. Please consider adding the anchors in the manual, the only way I figured how to use them all was peering at the source. This example does not work anymore, the output anchors need a space between 'out' and '+' or '-'. (yeah I know that's old).